# How to open Reminder Event Default screen using our app

Tags: ios, ios8, eventkit, ekeventkit

I am creating a app where i can set the reminder based on Location and date.Apple has already given the UI if you are using Reminder which has both option.Can any one help me out that how can i open that Create event screen.[image: Create Event either based on location or based on date]

Comment: what exactly do you need to know? you could create a tableviewcontroller in storyboard with static content and setup the ui like in the screen above.

Comment: hey @AndreSlotta thanks for your quick response, i just want to open this screen using my app, is it possible using of event kit?

Comment: as far as i know eventkit does not contain the UI but only the classes needed to create calendar events...

Comment: when you will open apple's reminder app and add some text to that then "i" button will be enabled once you click on i button it will open this screen and i want to open the same.

Comment: yeah, i got that. but there is no apple prepared viewcontroller. you have to set it up yourself!